# progress bar implementation on nodeBB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, model-view-controller, socket.io

I found a interesting site [nodBB](https://community.nodebb.org/), What interests me is the progress bar at the top of the page. I want to know how to implement this bar using javascript to represent the loading status of a view.

Is it a library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dig into the source code, found this. So now the answer is quite clear.

```
(function() {
    var e = app.refreshTitle, t = $(".loading-bar");
    $(window).on("action:ajaxify.start", function(e) {
        t.fadeIn(0).removeClass("reset")
    });
    $(window).on("action:ajaxify.loadingTemplates", function() {
        t.css("width", "90%")
    });
    app.refreshTitle = function(i) {
        t.css("width", "100%");
        setTimeout(function() {
            t.fadeOut(250);
            setTimeout(function() {
                t.addClass("reset").css("width", "0%")
            }, 250)
        }, 750);
        return e(i)
    }
})()
```